# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult<TValue> return additional common information

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1

I want to return additional common information in object of class Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult<>. This information should be stored in new properties. This class is sealed. How can I do it?

Should I use decorator or adapter pattern?

Maybe this additional common information for actions should be returned in a completely different way than using new properties?

Answer (score 0):

Generally to return additional common information we can use new ObjectResult(object value):

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Localization>> Get(long id)
    {
        var item = await _context.Localizations.FindAsync(id);

        if (item == null)
        {
            logger.Error(string.Format("LocalizationId: {0} not found.", id));
            return new ObjectResult(new DataActionResult(ResultActionCodes.ItemNotFound, string.Format("LocalizationId: {0} not found.", id))); ;
        }

        return item;
    }
```